# How to change pyplot background colour in region of interest?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with a datetime index:

```
            A  B
date            
2020-05-04  0  0
2020-05-05  5  0
2020-05-07  2  0
2020-05-09  2  0
2020-05-18 -5  0
2020-05-19 -1  0
2020-05-20  0  0
2020-05-21  1  0
2020-05-22  0  0
2020-05-23  3  0
2020-05-24  1  1
2020-05-25  0  1
2020-05-26  4  1
2020-05-27  3  1
```

I want to make a lineplot to track A over time and colour the background of the plot red when the values of B are 1. I have implemented this code to make the graph:

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmap = ListedColormap(['white','red'])

ax.plot(data['A'])
ax.set_xlabel('')
plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.pcolorfast(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(),
              data['B'].values[np.newaxis],
              cmap = cmap, alpha = 0.4)
plt.axhline(y = 0, color = 'black')
plt.tight_layout()
```

This gives me this graph:

[image]

But the red region incorrectly starts from 2020-05-21 rather than 2020-05-24 and it doesn't end at the end date in the dataframe. How can I alter my code to fix this?

Comment: I am having a hard time to reproduce the problem. What does cmap look like? Is mdates matplotlib.dates?

Comment: mdates is matplotlib.dates and cmap is a ListedColormap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change `ax.pcolorfast(ax.get_xlim(), ...` by `ax.pcolor(data.index, ...` you get what you want. The problem with the current code is that by using `ax.get_xlim()`, it creates a *uniform rectangular grid* while your index is not uniform (dates are missing), so the coloredmeshed is not like expected. The whole thing is:

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmap = ListedColormap(['white','red'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.plot(data['A'])
ax.set_xlabel('')

plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
#here are the two changes use pcolor
ax.pcolor(data.index, #use data.index to create the proper grid
          ax.get_ylim(),
          data['B'].values[np.newaxis], 
          cmap = cmap, alpha = 0.4, 
          linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
plt.axhline(y = 0, color = 'black')
plt.tight_layout()
```

and you get
[image]

Comment: I need a uniform red region. Why does your code result in visible vertical lines in the red region?

Comment: @kynnem try to add these two parameters `linewidth=0, antialiased=True` in the pcolormesh function?

Comment: @kynnem and for the why, if you don't specify these parameters, it depends on some global `rcParams` of the viewer used, so it is why they appeared

Answer (score 3):

I prefer `axvspan` in this case, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html) for more information.

This adaptation will color the areas where `data.B==1`, **including the potential where `data.B` might not be a continuous block**.

With a modified dataframe `data` from `data1.csv` (added some more points that are 1):

```
date        A   B
5/4/2020    0   0
5/5/2020    5   0
5/7/2020    2   1
5/9/2020    2   1
5/18/2020   -5  0
5/19/2020   -1  0
5/20/2020   0   0
5/21/2020   1   0
5/22/2020   0   0
5/23/2020   3   0
5/24/2020   1   1
5/25/2020   0   1
5/26/2020   4   1
5/27/2020   3   1
```

```
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data1.csv',index_col='date')
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.plot(data['A'])
plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.axhline(y = 0, color = 'black')

# in this case I'm looking for a pair of ones to determine where to color
for i in range(1,len(data.B)):
    if data.B[i]==True and data.B[i-1]==True:
        plt.axvspan(data.index[i-1], data.index[i], color='r', alpha=0.4, lw=0)

plt.tight_layout()
```

If `data.B==1` will always be "one block" you can do away with the `for` loop and just use something like this in its place:

```
first = min(idx for idx, val in enumerate(data.B) if val == 1) 
last = max(idx for idx, val in enumerate(data.B) if val == 1) 

plt.axvspan(data.index[first], data.index[last], color='r', alpha=0.4, lw=0)
```

Regarding "why" your data does not align, [@Ben.T has this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62159562/11305111).

**UPDATE**: as pointed out, the `for` loop could be too crude for large datasets.  The following uses numpy to find the falling and rising edges of `data.B` and then loops on those results:

```
import numpy as np
diffB = np.append([0], np.diff(data.B))
up = np.where(diffB == 1)[0]
dn = np.where(diffB == -1)[0]

if diffB[np.argmax(diffB!=0)]==-1:
    # we have a falling edge before rising edge, must have started 'up'
    up = np.append([0], up)

if diffB[len(diffB) - np.argmax(diffB[::-1]) - 1]==1:
    # we have a rising edge that never fell, force it 'dn'
    dn = np.append(dn, [len(data.B)-1])

for i in range(len(up)):
    plt.axvspan(data.index[up[i]], data.index[dn[i]], color='r', alpha=0.4, lw=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I do like your idea. the only concern I would have is if the dataframe is big, then looping and adding as many `axvspan` as 1 in the column B might be a bit long or memory consuming. do you have any knowledge about this? alos, the result would be slightly different than with `pcolor` because this version colors intervals (between 1s) and not from a 1 to the next date even if it is a 0 (like with pcolor), but it depends on OP's need :)

Comment: yes my `for` loop is a bit crude for large datasets.  I'll post an update using numpy to find the areas to color.  wrt coloring between 1s, this was my best guess on how a color scheme would work with dates... if only one date has a 1 what should be colored?

Comment: with pcolor, if you only have one 1 then from the date with the 1 to the next date in your data, it is colored, it is how the method works. I guess with your code it would just change the condition `if data.B[i]==True and data.B[i-1]==True:` to `if data.B[i-1]==True:` to get similar behavior :) but as I said, it depends on OP's need

Comment: I'm thinking `pcolorfast` is a better solution :)