# How to use correctly matplotlib's pcolor?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a 2d graph drawn using matplotlib and dataframe.

I followed the accepted answer in this question: [How to change pyplot background colour in region of interest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074055/how-to-change-pyplot-background-colour-in-region-of-interest)

My code was working as expected until maybe my last arch Linux update.
Since then, my code is not working anymore and I get following error:

```
[1493 rows x 5 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eco.py", line 148, in _show_alert
    ax.pcolor(df.index, ax.get_ylim(),df['alert'].values[np.newaxis])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1447, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5821, in pcolor
    X, Y, C, shading = self._pcolorargs('pcolor', *args, shading=shading,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5590, in _pcolorargs
    Nx = X.shape[-1]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

The code:

```
cmap = ListedColormap(['white','red'])
ax.pcolor(df.index, ax.get_ylim(),df['alert'].values[np.newaxis],
              cmap=cmap, alpha=0.5, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)
```

Where df is a pandas's dataframe instance, df.index timestamp index, and df['alert'] values that can be 0 or 1 (so I can map red color when alert=1).
The expected final result is a 2d graph (df['val']) with white background, or red background depending on df['alert'].

What am I doing wrong ?
Was I lucky if it was previously working ?
Was the API changed ? How am I supposed to know this kind of stuff if it is the case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to understand what you are doing wrong with the information provided. Here is a simple working example. Try to pinpoint the difference with your implementation, especially the type of the variables.

```py
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['10/25/2005','10/29/2002','01/01/2001','01/01/2000','01/01/1999','01/01/1997'],
    'A': [0,5,-1,3,4,0],
    'alert': [0,0,0,1,1,1]
})

# convert to type datetime
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data = data.set_index('date')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cmap = ListedColormap(['white','red'])
ax.plot(data['A'])
ax.set_xlabel('')
plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))

ax.pcolor(data.index, ax.get_ylim(),data['alert'].values[np.newaxis],
              cmap=cmap, alpha=0.5, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

plt.axhline(y = 0, color = 'black')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: You have 4 useless lines in your code (df is not used), but your code is working. I still dont understand why my code was not working. Before the call to pcolor I had few df.plot call. I had to change them to ax.plot and know it is working. So I m ok with that, and I will investigate later. Thank you