# Matplotlib line graph background colouring misaligned

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I currently have a line graph that plots a data column and I want to colour the background based on the number of another data column. This is how it's looking at the moment, the colour is ok but it's not lining up properly to the data:
[image: Line graph with misaligned colours]

This is my dataframe:

```py
                               Scores  Moods
Times
2022-12-05 08:25:19.618648       3      1
2022-12-05 08:37:47.121735       2      2
2022-12-05 09:25:13.647687       2      21
```

My current code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Times": times})
df["Scores"] = scores
df["Moods"] = moods
df = df.set_index("Times")
plt.plot(df["Scores"])
ax: axis.Axis.axes =plt.gca()
ax.pcolorfast(ax.get_xlim(),ax.get_ylim(),df["Moods"].values[np.newaxis],cmap="RdYlGn",alpha=0.4)
            
days = mdates.DayLocator()
days_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%D')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(days_fmt)
ax.margins(0)
            
#set plot title
plt.title("Mental workload for this week")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Mental workload")
plt.ylim(1,5)


plt.savefig('images/mwltrend.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

I've seen someone who has the same problem:
[How to change pyplot background colour in region of interest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074055/how-to-change-pyplot-background-colour-in-region-of-interest)
but for some reason the code doesn't work when I try to do their implementation:

```py
ax.pcolor(df.index,ax.get_ylim(),df["Moods"].values[np.newaxis],cmap="RdYlGn",alpha=0.4)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Dimensions of C (1, 3) are incompatible with X (3) and/or Y (2); see help(pcolor)
```

Any ways to get my desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by instead of using `df["Moods"].values[np.newaxis]` I used `np.tile(df["Moods"].values,(2,1))` to instead duplicate the array twice for both y bounds. Result now looks like this, which is pretty much exactly what I wanted:

[image: Accurate colouring graph]

Answer (score 0):

The error message `nextcord.errors.ApplicationInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Dimensions of C (1, 3) are incompatible with X (3) and/or Y (2); see help(pcolor)` means that the dimensions you're trying to plot do not match the dimensions of the plot itself.

You can try to use `np.meshgrid` to adjust the dimensions: `x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(df.index, ax.get_ylim())` (and now use `x_grid` and `y_grid` instead of `df.index` and `ax.get_ylim()` in your `ax.pcolor`!)

If the fix from the other SO post doesn't work, you might try to fidget around with the additional parameter `edgecolors` in the `ax.pcolorfast` method!

Comment: Let me know if fixing the error message helped (with the coloring) - and if not, I can explain on how to use `edgecolors` properly to achieve your results! :)

Comment: Just started debugging again, tried to use the meshgrid method but found the same problem. This is what the dataframe looks like: https://i.imgur.com/9bEM1V1.png

but I still get the same `Command raised an exception: TypeError: Dimensions of C (1, 3) are incompatible with X (3) and/or Y (2); see help(pcolor)` error